# tinyMCE does not discover correct plug-in path in IE10 and Chrome

Tags: tinymce

It took me a whole day to work this out, I am posting this for future reference.

I am setting up a news publishing site (powered by www.phpenter.net) that utilizes tinyMCE editor v 3.X, I did an upgrade to tinyMCE v4.0.26, updated some init parameters and all is good. I use Opera for development, so didn't spot the problem right away.

When I tested the site in IE10 and Chrome the editor would not load, I was getting an error:

```
Object doesn't support this action 
Line 27037    self.theme = new Theme(self, ThemeManager.urls[settings.theme]);
```

I also saw that all tinyMCE resources (JS, CSS) were not loading:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Paths were wrong :

```
http://mysite//plugins/visualblocks/plugin.min.js
```

instead of

```
http://mysite/scripts/tiny_mce/plugins/visualblocks/plugin.min.js
```

This was the case for all resources

This only took place in Chrome and IE, Opera was loading everything correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging, I found the relevant code in tinymce.js :

```
29191           // Get base where the tinymce script is located                         
29192                           var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');          
29193                           for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {          
29194                               src = scripts[i].src;       
29195                                       
29196                               // Script types supported:      
29197                               // tinymce.js tinymce.min.js tinymce.dev.js     
29198                               // tinymce.jquery.js tinymce.jquery.min.js tinymce.jquery.dev.js        
29199                               // tinymce.full.js tinymce.full.min.js tinymce.full.dev.js      
29200                               if (/tinymce(\.full|\.jquery|)(\.min|\.dev|)\.js/.test(src)) {      
29201                                   if (src.indexOf('.min') != -1) {    
29202                                       suffix = '.min';
29203                                   }   
29204                                       
29205                                   baseURL = src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf('/'));   
29206                                   break;  
29207                               }       
29208                           }           
29209                                       
29210                           // We didn't find any baseURL by looking at the script elements         
29211                           // Try to use the document.currentScript as a fallback          
29212                           if (!baseURL && document.currentScript) {           
29213                               src = document.currentScript.src;       
29214                                       
29215                               if (src.indexOf('.min') != -1) {        
29216                                   suffix = '.min';    
29217                               }       
29218                                       
29219                               baseURL = src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf('/'));       
29220                           }
```

On line 29200 there is a regex match for tinymce, however this would fail in my implementation because the script was renamed to tiny_mce.js from tinymce.js

When this failed, the script tries to lookup `document.currentScript` parameter which present in Opera but not in IE10 and Chrome.

So, to solve this, we can rename tiny_mce.js back to tinymce.js and edit all application references to it (original phpenter.net implementation is using `tiny_mce`), Or edit the regex to look for `tiny_mce` instead of `tinymce`.

Also, we could add a check for `document.currentScript` equivalent DOM properties in IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue as of tinyMCE 4.3.11. The proper work-around for this would be to preInit tinyMCE. Insert the following before you include the `tinymce.min.js` file. Change the `base` path to where your JS directory is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.tinymce = { suffix: "", base: "/absolute/path/to/js" }
</script>
```

For example, in Symfony2 I do the following in my Twig template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.tinymce = { suffix: "", base: "{{ app.request.baseUrl }}/js" }
</script>
```

*Note: Older versions of TinyMCE might have to use `window.tinyMCEPreInit` instead of `window.tinymce`*